# "Access your photos" permission dialog showing up in wrong view

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to change user's profile picture in IOS, in that the user can select a picture from gallery. But when I access the gallery using UIPickerController it asks for permission to access photos; but the permission alertview pops up on a different view in the app.
How can I always allow access to photos in my app or solve this pop up issue?

Comment: Can you try refining your title a bit to reflect the exact problem? Otherwise people may think it's about how to do this in general, which (as you know) can be found out easily by Googling.

Comment: I edited in a suggestion; feel free to roll it back to your original title if you don't like it.

Comment: The view on which the pop up appears is different; how to handle that??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to programmatically force access to photos.  Privacy issue!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to access a users photos you HAVE TO ask him. there is no way around it. of course this has to happen only once. as soon as the user allows / denies the access the only way to change this setting afterwards is for him to go to the settings app and change the permission there.

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be what the user is asking about?

Comment: **How can I always allow access to photos in my app [...]** - i think it is!

Comment: Read the question text.

Comment: ok. let us not use SO for a discussion like this. fact is: the **or** in the final question **How can I always allow access to photos in my app or solve this pop up issue?** indicates that there seem to be two questions. i answered one of them. that's fine for you i hope. :)